# syntax error near unexpected token fork()

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu-14.04

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main() 
{ 

    int some_value;

    printf("Forking process\n");

    fork();

    /* This part of the program is executed by two different proceses */
    printf("The process id is %d \n", getpid());
    some_value = getpid() + 10;
    printf("Some value is %d ", some_value);

    execl("/bin/ls","/bin/ls","-l",NULL);

    /* This line is not executed because of th execl function */
    printf("This line is not printed\n");
}
```

For this chunk of code I'm getting the following error:

```
./fork1.c: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `"Forking process\n"'
./fork1.c: line 8: ` printf("Forking process\n");'
```

It doesn't seem to me as a syntax error though.

Comment: What happens if you do: `gcc fork.c && ./a.out` ?

Comment: It works just fine! I was trying ./fork.c for some reason :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a shell script, it's C.

You have to compile it (e.g.: with `gcc`) and then run the created executable.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning that. I have already compiled it with gcc but when I'm trying to run it i'm getting the syntax error.

Comment: So you're running `fork` or `a.out`, not trying to run `fork.c`?

Comment: @GiorgosKaragiannopoulos: clearly you don't, it's visible in the output you've posed: `./fork1.c`[...]